# Distinct on date time key of dictionary

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary of `Dictionary<DateTime, double>>` type.

Need to do a distinct on dictionary where as a result it contains values for **unique month-year combination** ignoring the date.

```
1-May-14    -0.15
1-Apr-14    1.8
31-Mar-14   10
30-Mar-14   10
```

should give

```
1-May-14    -0.15
1-Apr-14    1.8
1-Mar-14    10
```

Comment: What have you tried to do to solve this problem?  What problems did you encounter in your attempted solutions?

Comment: I have a simple for loop and an entry table to maintain found combinations and value. Looking for a better cleaner approach. May be linq or something.

Comment: So you have a working solution?  In that case, "Code Review" is likely a better site for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a date from the year and month and group on that:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime, double>> grouped =
  dict.GroupBy(d => new DateTime(d.Key.Year, d.Key.Month, 1), d => d.Value);
```

Now you have a collection where each year-month value has one or more `double` values. You just have to decide what to do with the multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
     var  dates = new Dictionary<DateTime, double>(){

        {DateTime.Parse("2014-05-01"), -0.15},
        {DateTime.Parse("2014-04-1"), 1.8},
        {DateTime.Parse("2014-03-31"), 10},
        {DateTime.Parse("2014-03-30"), 10}
    };

    var uniqueDates = new Dictionary<DateTime, double>(new DateEqualityComparer());
    foreach(var item in dates) {        
        DateTime key = new DateTime(item.Key.Year, item.Key.Month, 1);      
        uniqueDates[key] = item.Value;

    }

class DateEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<DateTime>
{

    public bool Equals(DateTime  value1, DateTime value2)
    {
         if (value1.Month == value2.Month && value1.Year == value2.Year) return true;

         return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DateTime value)
    {

        int hash = value.Month ^ value.Year;
        return hash.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```